# Scale azure web sites using Azure Service Manager Cmdlets powershell for Azure Classic V1

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to scale (changing pricing tier or configurations) Web Site using ASM cmdlets powershell for Azure Classic V1.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am not able to change hosting package of a website using ASM cmdlets.